# hasOneThrough and hasManyThrough not working in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-one-through

I have the following tables

```
users          userdatas        workdays
---------      -----------      --------
id             id               id
               user_id
               workday_id
```

I would like to get a user's workdays (and later get all the users that have a specified workday, but one step at a time). I attempted several variations of this however it's not working. I believe the issue could be that workdays doesn't reference `userdatas`.

In the User model:

```
public function workday() {
    return $this->hasOneThrough('App\Workday', 'App\Userdata');
}
```

I've also defined the following:

In `Userdata`

```
public function workday() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Workday');
}
```

In `Workday`

```
public function userdatas() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Userdata');
}
```

Does the reverse through relationship have to be defined in `Workday`? Any tips to get this to work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're following wrong relationship. As per your Database table design it should be Many to many relationship(`belongsToMany`).

In User Model pass the relationship as below.

```
public function workdays() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Workday', 'userdatas','user_id','workday_id');
}
```

Comment: I think this is partially correct. It works in that I get a `Collection` with one item, however a `User` only has a single `Workday` related to it so this should return an instance of `Workday`. I believe `belongsTo` doesn't work here because `Workday` doesn't reference the `users` table.

Comment: @Sandy then your DB table design is incorrect way, If it have one to one relationship, then you need to store the `user_id` in `workday` table. I hope you understand what I am trying explain you :)

Comment: It's not one to one. For example, a `workday` is something like "Monday 8am to 11am". So many `users` can have this `workday` assigned, but each `user` can only have one `workday`

Comment: @Sandy Then your database schema is still wrong, if a user can only have one workday, but a workday can belong to many users, it should be a one-to-many relationship, so you would have a workday_id on the user, that way you can assign a single workday to multiple users, but each user can only have one workday assigned to  them.

Comment: @Remul Yes that is correct, but instead of having all this additional data in the `users` table, I created a `usersdata` table. Any `User` config is stored in the `usersdata` table, that has a `user_id` to reference to which user a given row belongs to, and a `workday_id` to reference which workday a user has.